Weak ergodicity of discrete birth death process
I am trying to understand the criteria of weak ergodicity through the Dobrushin coeffcient.
Let $P(m, k)$ be a transition matrix of a countable state space discrete time Markov chain.
Weak ergodicity means that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{u,v}||uP(m,k)-vP(m,k)||_1, \forall m$$
where $u, v$ are probability distributions.
Strong ergodicity means that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{u}||uP(m,k)-\pi||_1, \forall m$$
where $u, \pi$ areprobability distributions.
The chain is weakly ergodic if and only if the limit of Dobrushin coeffcients of transition matrices is zero.
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\delta(P(m,k))=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\sup_{i,j}\sum_l|p_{i,l}(m,k)-p_{j,l}(m,k)|=0$$
If a Markov chain is homogeneous, then $P(m, k)=P^{k-m}$ and weak ergodicity here should be equivalent to  the convergence of Dobrushin coeffcients of these matrix powers to zero.
Now take a discrete time homogeneous birth death process (on the state space of non-negative integers) with transition probabilities
$$p_{i,i+1}=p,\ p_{i,i-1}=q,\ p_{i,i+1}=r$$
With $p<q$.
This Markov chain is ergodic (in the sense of ergodicity for homogeneous Markov chains), thus it should be also weakly and strongly ergodic. So this should be also true
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\delta(P^k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\sup_{i,j}\sum_l|p_{i,l}(k)-p_{j,l}(k)|=0$$
However i don't see how this can be true. Probably i am miscalculating the Dobrushin coeffcients here, but i see that we can always find two rows of $P^k$ that are disjoint, i.e. for initial states that are far enough to be connected by $k$ steps. I mean they will have all zeros in one row where the other row has non-zeros and the other way around, so the variation will be 2 full sums of state probabilities  and the Dobrushin coeffcients are always 1 for all $k$. There should be a stupid flaw in my reasoning, but i can't find it immediately.
